# How to run multiple Web API 2 instances in the same project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, nopcommerce

I am using the nopCommerce platform. The main project is ASP.NET MVC 5. You can add other plugin projects as class library.

I implemented a REST service plugin using Web API 2, and now we purchased a plugin that also uses Web API 2 and we get the following error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route
>   collection. Route names must be unique. Parameter name: name

I found out that the problem is because both plugins call `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`.

Do you know of any way I could fix this?

How can I run two instances of Web API in a single project?

Comment: Can you actually see both plugins calling that, or are you just guessing?

Comment: Yes. I have the source code for both plugins. One is developed by me, the other one is bought, but I have the source code. In the question, I only wrote the code that is related to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's creating an issue. To solve that, You can remove `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` line from one plugin.
And that plugin won't work.

> Do you know of any way I could fix this?

Yes, I think one of the way is to create Owin different startup for both plugins and register your plugins route on startup.

Comment: What if I later choose to disable one of the plugins? I can't just remove `MapHttpAttributeRoutes` from one plugin ... How do you create "Owin different startup"?

Comment: @MariusStanescu: And please read[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @MariusStanescu, Can you please read my answer again, I'd not just stated to remove that code line!! IMHO, do not use `GlobalConfiguration` to register your route with *both* plugins, use it for one and for second use Owin startup point.